# Tabulator autocomplete custom editor and css. Cant display editor outside of a cell

Tags: javascript, css, autocomplete, tabulator

I use tabulator.js lib. My goal - to create autocomplete editior with values returned from API. I tried implement this as described in documentation in the [custom editiors](https://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/edit#) section.

My JS code:

```js
function AutocompleteEditor(cell, onRendered, success, cancel, editorParams) {

    var editor = document.createElement("input");
    editor.setAttribute("type", "text");
    editor.setAttribute("autocomplete", "off");
    
    editor.style.width = "100%";
    // editor.style.height = "100%";
    editor.style.boxSizing = "border-box";

    if (cell.getValue()) {

        editor.value = cell.getValue();
    }

    $(editor).autoComplete({
        minLength: 1,
        resolverSettings: {
            url: apiBaseUrl + 'ItemMatching/ItemCode',
        },
        formatResult: function (item) {
            return {
                value: item.vendorCode,
                text: item.vendorCode + " - " + item.vendorName,
            };
        },
    });

    $(editor).on('autocomplete.select', function (event, item) {

        if (item) {

            selectedManufacturer = item;
            $(editor).value(item.vendorName);
        }
    });

    onRendered(function () {

        console.log($(editor));
        editor.focus();
        editor.style.css = "100%";
    });

    function successFunc() {

        success(selectedManufacturer.vendorCode);
    }

    editor.addEventListener("change", successFunc);
    editor.addEventListener("blur", successFunc);

    return editor;
}
```

And I got behavior when autocomplete part "hided" by cell.
If I use standard html input type like ***date*** - no problem.
Please see attached pictures.

[image: Custom autocomplete issue]

[image: Input date - correct behavior]

Any suggestions needed how to fix or implement this (autocomplete part near a cell)?

PS I use bootsrap-autocomplete [bootstrap-autocomplete](https://bootstrap-autocomplete.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: There is already an autocomplete editor built into Tabulator that works with Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seing this is because Tabulator cells have overflow set to hidden. Most autocomplete widgets let you specify that the list should be appended to the body not the element itself,which over comes these sort of issues. But I cannot see that option on your chosen widget.

I would recommend using Tabulators built-in autocomplete editor that can offer all the functionality you are looking for. See the [Built in editor docs](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/edit#edit-builtin) for full details

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer and for the awesome component :)

I saw mentioned documentation...
But I'm not familiar with JS very well.

As I understood I need provide values as parameter or function returned object with values property.

I have above 400 k items for display in an autocomplete editor.

After enter in edit mode I do API request based on other cell value (to reduce items amount) and this the problem.

Customer use IE 11 :)

I can't use async await, fetch, not familiar with Babel. My implementation based on callbacks not works.

I will investigate more.

Comment: You can use the inbuilt one for that. And as long as you use a polyfill library like core.js it will work on ie11. There are IE11 compatible polyfills for both fetch and promises. If you are using Tabulator on IE 11 you must have most of these polyfills inplace already or Tabulator wouldn't be working. Checkout this link for more info http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/browsers